# How can i run ubuntu alongside windows 8 if my comouter have a bootlocker?

Tags: windows

My computer has a bootlocker
I have tried to bypass it but if i did, windows wouldn't boot anymore.

Advices?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean a dual boot.... [Install Ubuntu next to Windows 8 (UEFI dual boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236787/install-ubuntu-next-to-windows-8-uefi-dual-boot)

If by 'alonngside' you mean running at the same time, you might want to look into virtualbox.