# Ubuntu installation in BIOS mode

Tags: installation, dual-boot, windows, bios

I want to know what kind of installation is the best for me. I bought my computer with windows 7 preinstalled in it and I upgraded it to windows 8. It is in BIOS mode and I saw that i need to install ubuntu the same, in BIOS and I saw that ubuntu in BIOS is the classic installation, but what is THE CLASSIC INSTALLATION of Ubuntu ?

Thanks
Ubuntu User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIOS mode is absolutely fine. I have never head of "The CLASSIC INSTALLATION" of Ubuntu. There's Gnome Classic, which is a desktop environment. To switch to Unity log out, and where you login there should be a little icon. Click the icon and select "Ubuntu". Then you should start in Unity.

You can take a look [here](http://ubuntuxtreme.com/howto/how-to-change-desktop-environment-in-ubuntu-12-10/) for other desktop environments.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I want to know: should i take windows installation, cd installation or something with windows 8 UEFI

Comment: If you asking how to install ubuntu, I would recommend using a CD and installing it that way. This would mean changing you hard drive layout which will mean data loss.

Comment: and if I want it in dual-boot ? because I wanna keep windows

Comment: Same answer, you would just install windows and Linux side by side.  See [this post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236787/install-ubuntu-next-to-windows-8-uefi-dual-boot)

Comment: thx (i cant vote up)