# Windows failed to start when trying to intsall Ubuntu from a DVD

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, 13.04, windows-8, unetbootin

As the title says when I select UNetbootin as my OS I get an error saying that Windows failed to start. It advises me to repair using my Windows disc. Then I get this on the screen:

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \ubnldr.mbr  

  Status: 0xc0000007b  

  Info: The application or operating system couldn't be loaded because a required   
        file is missing or contains errors.
```

I am using Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13.04.

So I was already booting In legacy. On a lark I decided to try UEFI and that has made it so I cannot even boot windows after switching back to legacy. I get:

```
error no such partition  
grub rescue >
```

From the boot menu I can enter either **P2: TSSTcorp DVDWBD SN-406AB** or **P1: WDC WD7500BPKT-75PK4T0** or **Bigfoot Boot Agent**.

This is quickly going from bad to catastrophic. Please assist. I am in way over my head now. I removed the Ubuntu DVD and still no luck getting back into Windows.

Any advice on getting around this or understanding what the problem is would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed Ubuntu using Wubi? Are you trying to boot into Windows or into Ubuntu? Please edit your question to clarify.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Ubuntu next to Windows 8 (UEFI dual boot)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236787/install-ubuntu-next-to-windows-8-uefi-dual-boot)

Comment: Wubi does not work with systems that came preinstalled with Windows 8. Wubi is also broken in 13.04.

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me before. You need to go into your BIOS and disable UEFI and enable Legacy booting. That's what I did and it worked perfectly finefor me.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu have messed the boot loader apparently. The fix I used when i had a similar problem is located here: [Install Ubuntu next to Windows 8 (UEFI dual boot)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236787/install-ubuntu-next-to-windows-8-uefi-dual-boot) (your question is a possible duplicate of that post)

These two lines did it for me:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`

`sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install boot-repair Now run boot-repair`

Read the article and let us know if that helped or if our problem is related to that.