# Can I install Ubuntu over Win 8 without disabling UEFI?

Tags: boot, system-installation, windows-8, uefi

I own a Fujitsu Lifebook laptop with Win8 preinstalled. I want to install Ubuntu wiping Win8; however the BIOS is behind an unknown password, preventing me from disabling UEFI. 
When I run the Ubuntu live cd indeed the option of installing Ubuntu wiping the whole HDD appears. My question is: is it safe to choose this option? Will Ubuntu be able to boot reguarly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Ubuntu next to Windows 8 (UEFI dual boot)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/236787/install-ubuntu-next-to-windows-8-uefi-dual-boot)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed Windows 8 (64-bit) System (UEFI Supported)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate, the OP is asking if erasing Windows will work when there is an unknown BIOS password blocking access to the BIOS. User11111: Can you be a little more specific about "unknown BIOS password"? Do you mean to imply you aren't using UEFI? Is this a regular BIOS password?

Comment: In a first moment I thought it was a stock BIOS password, but when I called Fujitsu center they told me they do not set stock passwords. I don't really know who set it (still, obviously I am the legitimate owner of the laptop); however now my BIOS is locked and can't disable UEFI. My question is: if I erase completely win8 installing Ubuntu, can some issue arise in the process from the fact BIOS is locked and UEFI is still enabled?

Answer (score 1):

removing bios password can be performed by contacting support of fujitsu

then just disable secure boot, set boot devices order and you should be good to go

if you want to learn your win8 key for future purposes just install [this program](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/system-security/fr/belarc-advisor-review.htm)